# Solution set for trigonometric equation $\sin(3x) + \cos(3x) = 0$ on the interval $(-\pi, \pi)$

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Okay, so the options that have the red dots are my answers.  I am particularly uncertain about number 18. Please could you see if you agree with me.

Comment: Also not certain about question 20...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solutions for questions 17, 19, and 20 are correct.  As for question 18:
\begin{align*}
\sin(3x) + \cos(3x) & = 0\\
\sin(3x) & = -\cos(3x)\\
\tan(3x) & = -1\\
3x & = -\frac{\pi}{4} + k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}\\
x & = -\frac{\pi}{12} + \frac{k\pi}{3}
\end{align*}
Since $-\pi < x < \pi$, $-2 \leq k \leq 3$.  Thus, the solution set is 
$$\left\{-\frac{3\pi}{4}, -\frac{5\pi}{12}, -\frac{\pi}{12}, \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{7\pi}{12}, \frac{11\pi}{12}\right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

It's $$\sin(3x+45^{\circ})=0$$ or
$$3x=-45^{\circ}+180^{\circ}k$$ or
$$x=-15^{\circ}+60^{\circ}k,$$
where $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Thus, $$-180^{\circ}<-15^{\circ}+60^{\circ}k<180^{\circ}$$ or
$$-2.75<x<3.25,$$
which gives $k\in\{-2,-1,0,1,2,3\}$ and the 3) is valid.

Done!